# GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails - ACK=Failure

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have code GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails...where it wrong?
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public function callNVP($profileId) {
        $api_request = '&USER=' . urlencode('bestlifeXXXXX.gmaill.com')
                . '&PWD=' . urlencode('136XXXXXXX')
                . '&SIGNATURE=' . urlencode('XXXXXXXXJJJ4qi4-ASVptjmiE8Sqp4tXXXXXXCa')
                . '&VERSION=76.0'
                . '&METHOD =GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails'
                . '&PROFILEID=' . urlencode($profileId);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp'); // For live transactions, change to 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp'
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        // Uncomment these to turn off server and peer verification
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Set the API parameters for this transaction
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_request);

        // Request response from PayPal
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // If no response was received from PayPal there is no point parsing the response
        if (!$response)
            die('Calling PayPal to change_subscription_status failed: ' . curl_error($ch) . '(' . curl_errno($ch) . ')');

        curl_close($ch);

        // An associative array is more usable than a parameter string
        parse_str($response, $parsed_response);

        return $parsed_response;
    }
```

But it's return result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-12-10T03:49:09Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => cb2489449e84c
            [ACK] => Failure
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Timeout processing request
        )

)
```

What I want is:

```
(
    [PROFILEID] => I-CL7Kxxx
    [STATUS] => Active
    [AUTOBILLOUTAMT] => AddToNextBilling
    [DESC] => xxx
    [MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS] => 2
    [SUBSCRIBERNAME] => Dan
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2013-05-15T07:00:00Z
    [PROFILEREFERENCE] => 31571
    [NEXTBILLINGDATE] => 2013-05-16T10:00:00Z
    [NUMCYCLESCOMPLETED] => 1
    [NUMCYCLESREMAINING] => 18446744073709551615
    [OUTSTANDINGBALANCE] => 0.00
    [FAILEDPAYMENTCOUNT] => 0
    [LASTPAYMENTDATE] => 2013-05-15T14:52:04Z
    [LASTPAYMENTAMT] => 0.10
    [TRIALAMTPAID] => 0.00
    [REGULARAMTPAID] => 0.10
    [AGGREGATEAMT] => 0.10
    [AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT] => 0.00
    [FINALPAYMENTDUEDATE] => 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-05-15T14:55:58Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 225681xxx
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 64
    [BUILD] => 5908853
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => xxx
    [SHIPTOCITY] => xxx
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
    [SHIPTOZIP] => xxx
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRY] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United States
    [SHIPADDRESSOWNER] => PayPal
    [SHIPADDRESSSTATUS] => Unconfirmed
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Day
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
    [TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AMT] => 0.10
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [REGULARBILLINGPERIOD] => Day
    [REGULARBILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
    [REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
    [REGULARCURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [REGULARAMT] => 0.10
    [REGULARSHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [REGULARTAXAMT] => 0.00
)
```

Who can help me? Please...

Comment: what is the profile ID you trying to pass in? And is the profile ID created in Sandbox or Live?

Comment: In sandbox... 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp')

Comment: can you let me know your profile ID that you passed in? I will search for it

Comment: Are you want it? I-LA5TLTYBLNA9
action: GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails

I want STATUS(active, expired, suppended... etc) of it.

Comment: your API credentials of username and password seems to be invalid. You should not use your account login, but the API credentials supplied to you along with the SIGNATURE. Can you please check?

Comment: I checked. But, It's right. Now, What should I do? How edit?

Comment: urlencode('bestlifeXXXXX.gmaill.com') < I don't see how `_api1` is fitted in here. API username should have a `_api1` in the email address. Can you provide the full API username that you used?

Answer (score 0):

You've got this:

```
'&METHOD =GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails'
```

I think that space in there is causing an invalid request.  Try this:

```
'&METHOD=GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails'
```

Comment: No! It doesn't work.
I use action:SetExpressCheckout and action:ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus. it's work. But action: GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails then doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try what I'm telling you?  It's not seeing the correct method because of the space in the parameter name.  [Take a look here](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails.php) and you can see the call working successfully.

Comment: That sample is using my [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/), which I would recommend you take a look at.  PayPal's own integration team prefers it.  That sample works out of the box, as you can see, and it has the same thing for pretty much every PayPal API call available in the classic API.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely because of your API request(I am guessing its **Incorrect Profile ID**)

Can you try(click) the following link in your browser(substitute API credentials,Profile ID)

https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?&user=xxxxxxxxxx&pwd=xxxxxxxxxx&signature=xxxxxxxxxx&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails&PROFILEID=I-XXXXXXXXXXXX

And see what response you get.

I get **Internal Error**, when I used "I-XXXXXXXXXXXX" as profile id.

Comment: XXXX is anomymous. don't really... I see in forum Paypal, it doesn't allow GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails, because API don't support.

Comment: Provide the complete response you got when you used the link I provided in my answer